# Absolute value through bit manipulate quesion

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've been reviewing bit manipulation and have been looking at this page:
[http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs)

```
int v;           // we want to find the absolute value of v
unsigned int r;  // the result goes here 
int const mask = v >> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1;

r = (v + mask) ^ mask;
```

size of int is 4 and chars in byte is 8.  So basically I gather this is a mask for a 32 bit integer.
I understand for negative v this is supposed to create a mask of -1 and for positive numbers a mask of
0.  My question is why only shifting 28 bits instead of 31 bits?  Feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 31 bits, assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`.  The binary `*` operator has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than binary `-`, so this is parsed as `(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1`, which is `(4 * 8) - 1 == 31`.

Comment: Ah you're right.  Silly mistake on my part